# Why are there no questions related to the vim tag?

Tags: support, tags, bountied-tab

When I search the keyword vim on stackoverflow, there are lots of questions which are tagged with the [vim](/questions/tagged/vim) tag, but when I click the tag named vim, I am surprised to find that no questions use this tag. What's wrong? What happened?

What's more, when I click vim tag, it leads me to a page named the Featured tab. What is this?

Is the vim tag useless? If it is useless, why this tag is on the site?

Comment: No-repro. In the future, please use [meta] for such questions.

Comment: what is the relation between stack overflow and meta stack overflow? seems their database are a bit different, since the result returned is different when i search

Comment: Stack Overflow is for questions about programming. Meta Stack Overflow is for questions about Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your screenshot tells you exactly why - you are on the "Featured" tab and there are no vim questions with active bounty (which is what "featured" means here). Click "newest".

Comment: wow, it's a bit strange, when i click vim, it used to be no questions attached to this tag, but now there are lots of questions attached to this vim tag, what happened, why there is no questions attached to it hours ago?

Comment: This seems to come up quite often, maybe if you're on the featured tab of a tag with no featured posts it should redirect you to Newest

Answer (score 0):

It's a valid tag, and 7,264 questions attached to this tag by the time I browsed it, you may try to refresh your page.

Comment: i have refresh my browser for many times, with the same result, that is vim tag with no questions attached it. you may see the following screeshots with the link http://i.imgur.com/7pulK.jpg